# User Authentication via passcode in swift

Tags: authentication, swift, touch-id

I want to use TouchID to authenticate the user before running the app. Otherwise he can enter his passcode. I can't finde any examples to check the passcode. I know that there isn't a static view for the Code. But how I can compare the entered Code with passcode.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you mean the passcode of the device?

Comment: Yes of course! The passcode of the device

Comment: You can not, you do not have acces to it.